# Percentage of Column in Table

Tags: r

I am trying to make a few barplots in R. Here is what I have so far: [image]

For this particular chart it is not important to me how many responses there are per browser, I simply want to know which percentage was a yes and which percentage was a no for each browser.

How can I transform the table that I am using to use 'percentage of column' instead of number of results? Is there a way to transform each column by the sum of that column? (I am very new to R) Thanks!

**Edit:** Sorry for lack of information. I have not installed any extra packages, just r-base on Ubuntu (installed this morning). Here is the output of dput:

```
structure(c(11L, 32L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(2L, 4L
), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("No", "Yes"), c("Chrome", "Firefox", 
"Internet Explorer", "Safari")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

**Edit2:** I found this function which seems to do what I want but am not really sure why it works.

```
prop.table(mymat, margin=2)*100
```

Comment: You can start by providing a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Table you are using? What does it look like? You could try something like `ddply` from `plyr` or `aggregate`. Basically divide each count by the sum of counts in each group.

Comment: I understand what I want to do, I just don't know how to manipulate a table in that way. I have been playing around with functions and could probably write something that does it, but figured there has to be a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumes two levels

```
barplot(x / rep(apply(x, 2, sum),each=2))
```

[image: img]

```
> apply(x,2,sum)
       Chrome           Firefox Internet Explorer            Safari 
           43                 7                 1                 2
```

This is the margins over the columns.  It gives the column sums.  Now if we want to divide X by these values, it has to be in the right order.  The data is in column-major order, so when used as a vector for division, `apply(x,2,sum)` will recycle over the wrong elements -- transposed, if you will.

Setting `each=2` in the `rep` command applies one element of the result of the `apply` call to each column (by duplicating the element).  Thus the assumption that the number of levels is 2.

For a more general solution, you could use `each=nrows(x)`.

Comment: Matt, can you explain why this works? I understand the pieces, but not how it fits together. Thanks

Comment: As in @mathematical.coffee's answer, colSums(x) can replace the apply(x,2,sum) call.

Answer (score 2):

You could just calculate the percentage and plot it?

Percentage = Yes/total votes, `data['Yes', ]`  selects the 'Yes' column and `colSums` calculates totals per column, so:

```
barplot( data['Yes', ]/colSums(data) )
```

[image]

Is that what you meant?